# A simple if else in R that creates a new column dependent on the result

Tags: r, if-statement

I am stuck on what should be a fairly simple if else statement in R.

I have a data frame named `UK` that contains several columns, one of which is named `location` which contains the name of the UK city to which that row's data pertains.

My goal is to create a new column, named `capital` that will simply separate the rows into a binary `London` or `UK ex London`. I haven't done many if else statements and I'm struggling to get the syntax right, my attempt below:

```
if (UK$location[UK$location == "London"]) UK$capital <- "London" else UK$capital <- "UK ex London"
```

Should if else not be the best way to do this, I am happy to adopt a different method. Many thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @thelatemail points out, a simple Base R solution is

```
UK$capital <- ifelse(location=="London", "London","UK ex London")
```

If you start building more complex statements then I find `dplyr` to be useful, and for this exmaple the solution is

```
## set up some data
UK <- data.frame(location=c("London","Not London"), val=c("a","b"))

library(dplyr)
UK <- UK %>%
  mutate(capital = ifelse(location=="London", "London","UK ex London"))
```

Comment: Honestly, why use dplyr here? Just use `ifelse` and an assignment and be done with it. There's no grouping, ordering, or other manipulation and the base R version is simpler by far. `UK$capital <- ifelse(location=="London", "London","UK ex London")`

Comment: you don't *have* to use it I agree. It's just *a* solution, and If the OP were to start building more complex statements that are suited to `dplyr` then hopefully this will help.